# Unconventional data frame reshaping

Tags: r

I'm trying to reshape table from

```
col1| col2|col3|id
v1  | v2  | v3 |1
v2  | v1  | v3 |2
```

to

```
col1|col2|id
v1  | v2 | 1
v2  | v3 | 1
v2  | v1 | 2
v1  | v3 | 2
```

Basically create pair of following columns for each id.

Sorry for not clear title, but not sure how to describe what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the case presented:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(
    select(df, -col3),
    select(df,  col1=col2, col2=col3, id)
)
```

for more columns, assuming `id` is the last column:

```
library(dplyr)

NcolsToReduce <- ncol(df) - 2

lapply(1:NcolsToReduce, function(i){
  x <- select(df, i, i+1, id)
  names(x) <- c("col1", "col2", "id")
  x
  }) %>% bind_rows()
```

I think that'd work.

Comment: Looks good. What if there is much more columns? Is there a way to automate that based on ncol()?

Comment: hmmm..... so an id column, and many more columns, which you want to reshape to 2 columns plus the id?

Answer (score 3):

The solution below should be working for an *arbitrary number of columns* and an `id` variable which can be *any column* (not just the last one).

It uses `melt()` to reshape from wide to long format and `shift()` to get the next row as second column of the column pair:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "id")[
  , .(col1 = head(value, -1L), col2 = head(shift(value, 1L, type = "lead"), -1L)), by = id]
```

> ```
>     id col1 col2
> 1:  1   v1   v2
> 2:  1   v2   v3
> 3:  2   v2   v1
> 4:  2   v1   v3
> ```

#### Data

> ```
> library(data.table)
> df <- fread(
>   "col3| col2|col1|id
> v1  | v2  | v3 |1
> v2  | v1  | v3 |2",
>   sep = "|")
> ```

Comment: a shorter version: `melt(setDT(df), id = "id")[, .(col1 = head(value, -1L), col2 = tail(value, -1L)), by = id]`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
Dat$New=apply(Dat[,1:3],1,function(x) toString(rollapply(x, 2, FUN=function(z) paste(z,collapse =';'))))
NewDat=Dat[,c('id','New')]
NewDat=NewDat%>%
    transform(New = strsplit(New, ",")) %>%
    unnest(New)

NewDat[,c('col1','col2')]=str_split_fixed(NewDat$New,';',2)

NewDat
  id    New col1 col2
1  1  v1;v2   v1   v2
2  1  v2;v3   v2   v3
3  2  v2;v1   v2   v1
4  2  v1;v3   v1   v3
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The idea is to first convert the data from wide format to long format. After that, duplicate the rows in the middle of each id group, change the column number, and then convert it back to wide format.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- data_frame(col1 = c("v1", "v2"),
                 col2 = c("v2", "v1"),
                 col3 = c("v3", "v3"),
                 id = c(1L, 2L))


# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Cols, Value, -id) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(c(1, 2, 2, 3)) %>%
  mutate(Cols = paste0("col", rep(1:2, each = 2))) %>%
  mutate(id2 = rep(1:2, 2)) %>%
  spread(Cols, Value) %>%
  select(col1, col2, id)

# View the result
dt2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
   col1  col2    id
* <chr> <chr> <int>
1    v1    v2     1
2    v2    v3     1
3    v2    v1     2
4    v1    v3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution, assuming the id column is the last column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

rbindlist(lapply(1:(ncol(df)-2), function(x) df[, c(x,x+1,ncol(df)), with = FALSE]))[order(id)]

#    col1 col2 id
# 1:   v1   v2  1
# 2:   v2   v3  1
# 3:   v2   v1  2
# 4:   v1   v3  2
```

The equivalent using base is similar, but a bit messier and probably less efficient.

```
#setDF(df)
df2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:(ncol(df)-2), function(x) setNames(df[, c(x,x+1,ncol(df))], names(df)[c(1,2,ncol(df))])))
df2[order(df2[,3]),]
```